# Alias for a function signature

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am implementing the kNN algorithm in Haskell. I therefore need distance functions.
The first one works well

```
import Data.Composition
import Data.Vector

taxicab :: Num a => Vector a -> Vector a -> a
taxicab = Data.Vector.sum .: Data.Vector.zipWith (\ x y -> abs $ x - y)
```

How can I create an alias `Distance` for `Num a => Vector a -> Vector a -> a`?

I could so write:

```
taxicab :: Distance
```

Comment: What you want is a [type *synonym*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_synonym). I don't think it's possible (or easy) to achieve exactly what you want. You could easily do: `type Distance a = Vector a -> Vector a -> a` and use `taxicab :: Num a => Distance a` though. If you want the dirty way you could use [`LANGUAGE CPP`](https://guide.aelve.com/haskell/cpp-vww0qd72) to define `Distance` as a macro but this should be avoided at all costs...

Comment: Parameterize the type `Distance` is a good idea indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you create a type alias for another type:

```
type Distance a = Num a => Vector a -> Vector a -> a
```

In fact functions are "type constructors": if you write `a -> b`, you have, in a more canonical form, written `(->) a b`, so that means that you have basically written:

```
type Distance a = Num a => (->) (Vector a) ((->) (Vector a) a)
```

Note however that we need to add a type parameter `a` here, so your `taxicab` is of type:

```
taxicab :: Distance a
```

Comment: With `RankNTypes` you can move the type parameter: `type Distance = forall a. Num a => Vector a -> Vector a -> a`, giving the desired `taxicab :: Distance`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to define a [type synonymn](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_synonym) (or see [this other page](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html)). It is not directly possible to include the class constraint *without a parameter*¹, but you can have a parametrized type synonym:

```
type Distance a = Vector a -> Vector a -> a

taxicab :: Num a => Distance a
```

This allows you to have define `Distance`s with different constraints.

---

¹ <sub>I was initially mistaken: you can if you add a parameter.</sub>